# Order of ALV columns (with CL_SALV_TABLE)

Tags: abap, alv

I have a program which displays a simple table based on the class `CL_SALV_TABLE`, and I'd like to position the column `CURRCODE` at the fifth position, instead of 4 currently (default order defined in database table `SCARR`), as shown here:

[image: Simple ALV output with column to be moved]

How can I do that?

Here is the current source code (compiles with ABAP version 7.40) :

```
  SELECT * FROM scarr INTO TABLE @DATA(scarr_s).

  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = DATA(salv)
    CHANGING
      t_table      = scarr_s ).

  salv->display( ).
```

NB: if you want to reproduce and the table `SCARR` is empty, execute the program `SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR` to fill it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in two steps, **before** the call of the method `display` :

- Call the method **`GET_COLUMNS`** of the ALV instance (of class `CL_SALV_TABLE`), to get the instance of the class `CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE` corresponding to all columns.
- The latter class has a method **`SET_COLUMN_POSITION`** to change the position of a given column whose name is passed as an argument.

Here is the source code:

```
  SELECT * FROM scarr INTO TABLE @DATA(scarr_s).

  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = DATA(salv)
    CHANGING
      t_table      = scarr_s ).

  salv->get_columns( )->set_column_position( columnname = 'CURRCODE' position = 5 ). " <== ADD THIS LINE

  salv->get_columns( )->set_optimize( ).
  salv->display( ).
```

Result:

[image: Simple ALV output with column moved as expected]

NB: I also use the method `SET_OPTIMIZE` so that the width of all columns is automatically adjusted to their contents (but it's not related to the question).